# Postman json syntax problem when try to use _bulk of elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, postman

I tried to use the elastic search in Postman.
I created indexes, I inserted some documents separately, it works fine.
But I unable to use /_bulk, how can I parametrize?
The following at the row 2 show "End of file expected"

[image]

I saw some similar example for example:
https://queirozf.com/entries/elasticsearch-bulk-inserting-examples

I have no idea how can I fix it. I wrapped it curly braces but the result is the same.

Comment: You can still run it, it will work, it's just that Postman doesn't understand the newline-delimited JSON format.

Comment: @Val, Thank you it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got everything done correctly. Just push the Send button, it will work.

Here are the important points when sending bulk queries via Postman:

1. Use the POST HTTP method as it's the correct one to use for the `_bulk` endpoint
2. In the body tab, select "Raw" and the JSON format int he pick list to the right (that will add the mandatory `Content-type: application/json` header in the Headers section)
3. Add a new line after the last document (i.e. line 5)

That's it, you're done!

Comment: Can I have another question?
I created a public docker repository, how can I add my docker container to that repository?

Comment: Please create a new thread since this is a new unrelated question, thank you